# Group stream elements and sum a field using JQ

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I am trying to group several items by their name based on the JSON-Data. Furthermore I want to calculate the sum of the size. Therefore I am using jq to transforming the data. Attached you see the raw data.

```
{
  "fields": {
    "issuetype": {
      "name": "Server"
    },
    "size": 2
  }
}
{
  "fields": {
    "issuetype": {
      "name": "Server"
    },
    "size": 2
  }
}
{
  "fields": {
    "issuetype": {
      "name": "Hardware"
    },
    "size": 0.58
  }
}
```

The transformed data should be structered like this:

```
[
  {
    "item": "Hardware",
    "size": 0.58
  },
  {
    "item": "Server",
    "size": 4
  }
]
```

I am using the following code

```
jq -s < input.json "group_by( .fields.issuetype.name ) | .[] | item: .[0].fields.issuetype.name), size:([.[].fields.customfield_1234] | add)" > transformedData.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there. To construct objects, you need object contructors.

```
  group_by(.fields.issuetype.name)
| map({item: .[0].fields.issuetype.name, size: map(.fields.size) | add})
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/b0bJgoBa7Z)</sup>